# How in Kotlin on Android can a null pointer exception occur in an immutable list during a or each loop?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm getting a RARE null pointer exception in the following code:

```
class Artist {
  fun draw(canvas: Canvas, state: State){
    state.drawableObjects.forEach { 
      it.draw(canvas) //NULL POINTER!?! Can not call draw(Canvas) on null object
    }
  }
}

class State {
  var drawableObjects = listOf<DrawableObject>()
    set(value) {
      field = value.filter { it.isVisible } // Why not crash here if null?
    }
}

class DrawableObject(val isVisible: Boolean) {
   fun draw(canvas: Canvas) { }
}
```

How is this possible? The list drawableObjects is immutable. It also does not allow null objects. When the list is changed an entirely new list is set to prevent modification during the draw call.

I should definitely mention that multiple threads are involved. 2 threads only. One calling Artist.draw() and a second calling State.drawableObjects = listOf()

Comment: Could you include `Artist.draw` call , please?

Comment: Are multiple threads involved in this logic?

Comment: Where and how are you setting `drawableObjects`? For example, are you parsing some JSON with Gson, and that is where the `drawableObjects` value comes from? Bear in mind that Kotlin's nullability guarantees are limited to Kotlin code, and objects created from Java code could well be `null` yet still make it into `drawableObjects`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am parsing with Gson. I'm not sure if that's my issue but it sounds like a correct answer to my question.

Comment: You sure, that you don't have any null object in the drawableObjects list? I would suggest to do a filterNotNull() on the state.drawableObject. Would look like state.drawableObjects.filterNotNull().forEach

Comment: I wonder if this is somewhat related to my issue too. I am seeing this behavior on immutable empty arraylists and immutable fixed size arrays of optionals.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know your data structures, so let's take a simpler case.

Suppose you are trying to populate a `List<String>` in Kotlin. `String` is non-nullable, so your Kotlin code will expect that all elements in the `List` to be not `null`.

However, it is possible that your `List<String>` is coming from Java code. In Java, `null` is perfectly fine to put in a `List`. And that Java code does not have to be yours — it could be from a library, such as Gson.

So, suppose you have Gson parse this JSON:

```json
[
  "the",
  "quick",
  "brown",
  null,
  "jumped",
  "over",
  "the",
  "lazy",
  null
]
```

Gson will be happy to parse that into a Kotlin `List<String>`, and Kotlin's JVM interop will allow it. But, when you start iterating over that `List<String>`, you will crash with a `NullPointerException` for the `null` elements.

Similary, Gson will leave Kotlin properties as `null` when parsing a JSON object that is missing some of those properties. Suppose you have:

```kotlin
data class Something(foo: Int, bar: Int)
```

and:

```json
{ foo: 42 }
```

Gson will happily create a `Something` instance with `bar` set to `null`.

So, my guess, based on your one comment, is that Gson is giving you `null` values in your `List<DrawableObject>` based on its parsing rules. You can address this by making that be a `List<DrawableObject?>` and then doing something about the `null` elements (filter them out, skip them during your `forEach` loop, etc.).

Comment: I think the implication is that filtering by ``it.isVisible`` in the setter should at least throw an NPE if any of the values are null, so the final list is guaranteed to only have non-null items

Comment: @cactustictacs: That's a good point. I can't explain that, other than perhaps there are some differences between the code as presented in the question and the code that is running (and is actually generating the `NullPointerException`).

Comment: I'm wondering if the compiler is skipping that filter line entirely, since ``isVisible`` is a ``val``, so it's always true anyway. So if you *did* pass in some nulls from the Java side, it wouldn't know!

Comment: It's a very interesting answer. However, we don't save DrawableObject. They are saved as a model of the object and if they were null when turned back into DrawableObject then there would be a null pointer then. The whole code base is very strict about not using nulls.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is the answer, but I have seen somethign similar in my own project and have gotten around it by using vars and doing the following:

```
@Suppress("SENSELESS_COMPARISON")
if(myImmutableThatShouldNotBeNull == null){
   myImmutableThatShouldNotBeNull = MyClass()
}
```

Or in your case:

```
@Suppress("SENSELESS_COMPARISON")
if(canvas == null){
   phone.throwOffCliff()!!.now()
}
```